# Oracle - "record" constant

Tags: database, oracle

i would like to create procedure for throwing application errors. This procedure should be placed in separate package.

```
procedue Raise_Error(error_code) is
err t_Error;
begin
      err:= error_list(error_code);
      raise_application_error(err.error_number, err.message);
end;
```

So i created types inside the package:

```
type t_Error is record (error_number INTEGER, message VARCHAR2(200));
type t_Error_List is table of t_Error index by VARCHAR(30);
error_list t_Error_List ;
```

How can i create list of error constants like this:

```
const1 t_Error := t_Error (-200001, 'first message');
const2 t_Error := t_Error (-200002, 'second message');

error_list ('code1') := const1;
error_list ('code2') := const2;
```

Thanks a lot.
Bob

Answer (score 1):

You can create the error table in the package's `begin`/`end` block (where it will be created for each session that calls the package), but you can't instantiate a record like that; you need to set the field values independently:

```
create package body error_pkg as
  procedure Raise_Error(error_code in varchar2) is
    err t_Error;
  begin
    err := error_list(error_code);
    raise_application_error(err.error_number, err.message);
  end Raise_Error;

begin
  error_list ('code1').error_number := -20001;
  error_list ('code1').message := 'first message';
  error_list ('code2').error_number := -20002;
  error_list ('code2').message := 'second message';
end error_pkg;
/
```

With a dummy PL/SQL block to call the procedure:

```
begin
  error_pkg.raise_error('code2');
end;
/

Error report:
ORA-20002: second message
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.ERROR_PKG", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/19cf3/2).

I'm not sure this is a good idea though. You're losing the stack trace of the original problem - you don't know where the `raise_error` call was made from. Maybe that doesn't matter for your own errors; but would be a bad idea if you're catching a real exception and calling this instead.

Comment: Full stack trace remains the same, just check output at your example on SQLFIddle: `ORA-20002: second message [... skip ...] at line 2 : begin error_pkg.raise_error('code2'); end;`. I.e. source of error can be easily determined. From my point of view it's good approach to maintain consistent error list across entire project, but use of constants to define error codes are debatable.

Comment: @ThinkJet - yes, I was mostly worried about this being called from an exception handler, but didn't explain that very well; and no real reason to think that anyway.

Comment: @Alex_Poole Ok. I share your concerns, especially because just yesterday I was faced with a situation where one programmer intercepted a system error and presented it as an business-level error. Such misunderstanding cause an absence of any information about a source of an error. So, usage of such pattern must be well documented and it's usage must be enforced among all members of development team.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
All these "custom errors" are defined in c# code (enum) and whole package is generated via text template from VS. These errors should be used for handling custom errors, mainly in triggers.

Comment: @TomasDlouhy - great, then I withdraw my concerns *8-)